# update one column on one click

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have made a plug-in for WordPress. You can enter new projects from the backend and the GUI in this plug-in.
When you enter it from the backend it gets status value "0", when you insert from the GUI status gets value "1".

This is because when someone from the GUI enter a new project it has to be accepted by the admin in the backend.

I have a DataBase with the next information in it, the table name is:

wp_ivs_canvas_tabel
[image: wp_ivs_canvas_tabel]

In the backend the admin can click on accept or deny.
[image: backend]

What i want is:
When the admin clicks on accept, that value "1" from status change into value "0".
Like a update function.

I hope someone can point me to the right direction.Please help me how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance .

Comment: Can you add a query in which you change the value in the database to 0, to the action of the button?

Comment: i dont have a query because i don't know how to start, i'am a bit new with php

Answer (score 2):

just update the row when click on button..
use jquery/ajax
First of, call the jquery library like this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.slim.js"></script>
```

create a file, for example script.js somewhere. and then call that one like this..

```
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then make the button click in your script-file something like this..

```
   $('#button').click(function(){      

    $.ajax({
id = this.id;
    data= '1';
     var updArray  = {data:data, id:id};
                url: "updQuery.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: array,
                success: function(respons){
                   console.log('succe');
                },
                error: function(){
                    console.log(respons);
                }
            })
```

then you create a php-file for example updQuery.php with the following query in it. You will also need som connection data aswell in that php-file.

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$data = $_POST['data'];
     $sql = "UPDATE table SET column = :status WHERE id = :id" ;
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array(
            'status'  => $data,
            'id'  => $id
        ));
```

Sometthing like that, with some modification will probably do it for you.

Comment: missing a parameter & value ( `:id` ) from the execute method

Comment: I have never used jquery/ajax before.. so i don't really know how that works